# page array missing from signed_request

Tags: request, facebook-php-sdk, signed

I have a page tab app created and hosted on heroku.  When a normal user clicks the tab on the page, the page loads and askes the user to login. I press the login button and the page loads but the signed request is missinfg the page array.

```
Facebook Object ( 
   [appId:protected] => 110227059110031 
   [appSecret:protected] => 365d05bfd0eac475a2b91c88c9bc8136 
   [user:protected] => 100003680202334 
   [signedRequest:protected] => Array ( 
         [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 
         [code] => 2.AQDVPZFl6Emi1.3600.1333494000.003680202334|Chl0OfvzKbOA_8sAi1J3h3xeqwk 
         [issued_at] => 1333489589 
         [user_id] => 100003680202334 ) 
   [state:protected] => 
   [accessToken:protected] => 
   [fileUploadSupport:protected] => )
```

It's missing 
          [page] => Array ( [id] => 125391070851681 [liked] => [admin] => 1 )

If I goto the page with the developer account it shows the page array.

Any ideas?

Comment: having the same problem. Anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 0):

this usually happen when you access facebook with http but facebook load content of you app using https or the other way around. If you used template app provide by heroku just comment out "force https" section of your code.